# how to send muliptle requests and make sure the response comes back within a second in python

Tags: python

I am trying to validate what the throttle limit for an endpoint using python code.
Basically I have set Throttlelimit on the endpoint I am testing is 3calls/sec. The test does 4 calls and checks the status codes to have atleast 1 429 response.
The validation I have fails sometimes because it looks like the responses take more than a second to respond. The code I tried are:
Method1:

```
request = requests.Request(method='GET', url=GLOBALS["url"],    params=context.payload, headers=context.headers)
context.upperlimit = int(GLOBALS["ThrottleLimit"]) + 1
reqs = [request for i in range(0, context.upperlimit)]
with BaseThrottler(name='base-throttler', reqs_over_time=(context.upperlimit, 1)) as bt:
    throttled_requests = bt.multi_submit(reqs)
context.responses = [tr.response for tr in throttled_requests]
assert(429 in [ i.status_code for i in context.responses])
```

Method2:

```
request = requests.get(url=GLOBALS["url"], params=context.payload,      headers=context.headers)
url = request.url
urls = set([])
for i in range(0, context.upperlimit):
    urls.add(grequests.get(url))
context.responses = grequests.map(urls)
assert(429 in [ i.status_code for i in context.responses])
```

Is there a way that I can make sure all the responses came back in the same second and if not it should try again before failing the test.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using requests and grequests library. You can set a timeout as explained in the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) and also for [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

## Plain requests

```
requests.get(url, timeout=1)
```

## Using grequests

```
grequests.get(url, timeout=1)
```

Timeout value is "number of seconds"

Answer (score 0):

Using `timeout` won't necessarily ensure the condition that you are looking for, which is that all 4 requests were received by the endpoint within one second (not that each individual response was received within one second of sending the request).

One quick and dirty way to solve this is to simply time the execution of the code, and ensure that all responses were received in less than a second (using the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module)

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
context.responses = grequests.map(urls)
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
if elapsed < 1:
    assert(429 in [ i.status_code for i in context.responses])
```

This is crude because it is checking round trip time, but will ensure that all requests were received within a second. If you need more specificity, or find that the condition is not met often enough, you could add a header to the response with the exact time the request was received by the endpoint, and then verify that all requests hit the endpoint within one second of each other.